# Locked myself out of Group Policy Management with no access to regedit

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I recently locked myself out of group policy management through Local Computer Policy > User Configuration > Administrative Template > Windows Components > Microsoft Management Console > Restrict users to the explicitly permitted list of snap-ins. My regedit is also disabled and I cannot access the group policy editor even though I am an admin. Please help me restore access. {E12BBB5D-D59D-4E61-947A-301D25AE8C23} is the SID I receive when trying to access group policy management. I did not know that these policies would apply to administrator accounts as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remote access registry, or use the reg command or powershell to access it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this powershell command to delete the `RestrictToPermittedSnapins` registry value:

```perl
Remove-ItemProperty HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MMC -Name RestrictToPermittedSnapins
```

Then, do **not** reboot, open the group policy editor again and revert your change.

Comment: This will not work as I have locked myself out of Regedit.

Comment: @byte69 You don't need access to regedit for this command to work...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing a third party group policy editor called [Policy Plus](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus) (which is open source!) and I was able to enable the the group policy editor from there.